Experimental Design: Selecting value of $n$ given desired width of credible interval
Note that this is a cross post from here. I realize this is probably a better space
Suppose I have $n$ IID Bernoulli trials with $k$ successes. Assume that as a prior we are assuming that $P(\theta)$ is uniform on $[0,1]$.
We can pretty easily use Bayes theorem to represent the posterior distribution here
$$
P(\theta|n,k)=\frac{\theta^k(1-\theta)^{n-k}}{\int_0^1\theta^k(1-\theta)^{n-k}d\theta}
$$
However now suppose that we are going to build up an experiment to run to predict $\theta$ given this prior. What we would like to know is the answer to the following question

Question: What value of $n$ is necessary to guarantee that regardless of the value of $k$, the $95\%$ credible interval will have width of at most $.1$?

I think fundamentally I struggle to understand how we compute the credible intervals, which makes me unable to numerically come up with a good answer. If someone could show how you would answer this question I would appreciate the help and I would adjust the methodology myself in the event I want to change the width or $\alpha$
